# How to get Newtonsoft.Json / Json.Net to parse past unrecognized characters?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, stringreader

I am trying to use Newtonsoft.Json to parse JSON logs generated from a testing station. Since the testing process may result in a slightly corrupted JSON content, I need to be able to parse through corrupt data. More specifically, when the parser encounters any corruption or unrecognized characters, I'd like to attempt to skip the current line and continue parsing on the next line.

I have been exploring the library and I haven't found a solution yet. Here is the snippet where the parser is stopping.  I can't seem to advance the stream independent of the parser.

```
StringBuilder jsonBuffer = new StringBuilder();
jsonBuffer = "...";

StringReader sr = new StringReader(jsonBuffer.ToString());
JsonTextReader jr = new JsonTextReader(sr);
jr.SupportMultipleContent = true;
bool go = true;
while (go) {
    try {
        go = jr.Read();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.Write("Oops! JSON Read Exception: ");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        // can't continue past here...
    }

    if (!go || jr.TokenType == JsonToken.Undefined) break;

    if (jr.Value != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}, Value: {1}", jr.TokenType, jr.Value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", jr.TokenType);
}
```

Some examples of the types of corruption I'm hoping to skip:

- "key": ""double quoted value""
- "key": "incomplete value
- incomplete objects such as missing ']' or '}'

I know the last item will take some more complex logic to unroll any nested objects, but this is more of a 'nice-to-have' whereas 1 and 2 are must-have.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
John

Comment: Can you give some examples of what this corruption might look like?

Comment: Sure, added some examples in the post.

Comment: Assuming the content is broken down by line, move the reading outside of the parsing (instead of relying on JsonTextReader). So basically: Open File, Read Line, Parse with Json.net, continue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ms` is a stram to your log file...

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
{
    do
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            JObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(line) as JObject;
            obj.Dump();
            Console.WriteLine("Foo: {0}", obj["foo"]);
        }
        catch (JsonReaderException jex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MALFORMED: {0}", line);
        }
    }
    while (!sr.EndOfStream);
}
```

Which will:

1. Open file for reading
2. Read each line individually.
3. Attempt to parse the line into an object (JObject)

   - On success, dump property value
   - On failure, show error message
4. Check for EOF (End of File)

   - If not EOF, return to step 2.
   - If EOF, exit.

That will process the most lines while passing over failures. You can then modify the `catch{}` block to use a more intense interrogation or write out to a post-log for further processing.

Comment: Makes sense; good approach. I'll give it a try in the morning. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Gave this a try but the problem here is that DeserializeObject throws an exception when it encounters incomplete JSON objects.  For example:  ,{"foo": "bar"  fails because of the comma and the open brace, which were part of previous legal JSON content.